# How to get OS and version of every server on network?

Tags: windows, nmap, operating-system

This is a case of "we are where we are". I'm a developer and I've been asked to get a list of every server on our network (IP and hostname) along with the OS version

We exclusively use Windows machines.

My first instinct was to use **nmap** but I'm unsure what syntax/values I would need. I'm on a VPN over WiFi but can RDP onto a server at work if needed. I tried using the gateway addy (with /24) but that yoelded next to nothing. So I need to use something like 10.*.*.* with nmap instead?

How would I essentialy see what servers are on the network and find out their IP/hostname/OS version?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

If the devices are joined to a Active Directory Domain you can try with PowerShell remoting, but that should be enabled already:

```
$adcomputer=(Get-ADComputer -Filter *).Name
 
Invoke-Command -ComputerName $adcomputer -Scriptblock {(Get-WMIObject win32_operatingsystem) | Select Name, Version} -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue
```

Personally I would push back and advise for an device inventory solution.